# Silverlight Toolkit TreeView control and expandability

Tags: c#, silverlight, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Is it possible to configure the TreeView control in the Silverlight tookit such that some or all of the hierarchy levels will be automatically expanded and ideally something that can't be collapsed at that level.

I'm using this control in large part due to the ease of handling hierarchical data and the ease with which I CAN expand/collapse levels.  I'm being asked to do this selectively (i.e. only at the first level should I allow expand/collapse).  I'm examining a Hierarchical Data Template to try and make this happen, but am having little luck and will certainly consider other options including a different control entirely if need be.  My boss DOES want me to avoid having to purchase a control if at all possible.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an FYI for the community.  I was provided and answer to this question [here](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/68462.aspx).  The upshot is that this can be accomplished with a combination of data templates and styles.